# How to query SOAP based endpoint using Spring WS by passing pre generated SOAP Request instead of XML payload?

Tags: spring, webservice-client, spring-ws

Need to query SOAP based endpoint using Sprint WS - but here instead of passing XML payload I will have pass a generated SOAP Request itself. I was using org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate for this purpose right now ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
ClientMessageCallBack _callBack = 
                new ClientMessageCallBack("yournamespaceuri/operationx");

final String _message = 
        "<ns1:operationx xmlns:ns1="yournamespaceuri"></ns1:operationx>";

StreamSource _source = new StreamSource(new StringReader(_message));
// the result will be output in the console
StreamResult _result = new StreamResult(System.out);

// suppose you have a reference to webServiceTemplate
webServiceTemplate.sendSourceAndReceiveToResult(_source,_callBack, _result);
```